# How do get custom pagination class working for django rest framework v3.6

Tags: django, rest, pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a custom pagination class on a ViewSet, as per [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/), but the pagination settings are just not doing a single thing. Here's the code for my ViewSet.

```
from rest_framework import status, permissions, viewsets
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class ProductViewSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    pagination_class = ProductViewSetPagination
    # ...

    def list(self, request):
        #get_queryset is also overridden to accept filters in query_params
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if not queryset.exists():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I even added some defaults to the settings.py file, but I'm still getting all the product instances on a single page on the `product-list` view. I've tried adding `page` and `page_size` query parameters to the URL; this doesn't change anything.

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
```

What am I missing?

Comment: do you use default list method  or override it?

Comment: It's overridden. I've added the code.

Comment: I take it that if you override the list method you must implement your own pagination then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pagination added in the super list, so try:

```
    def list(self, request):
        #get_queryset is also overridden to accept filters in query_params
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        if not queryset.exists():
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

        return super(ProductViewSet, self).list(request)
```